# JAVASCRIPT variable no changing in a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I cant seem to get a function to work. I am coding a web text based game in javascript. What I want to happen is for the lootKey to be set to nothing and the key to be set to 'key{br}' when the button is clicked but it is not working.

Here is my code..

```
var lootKey = "";
var key = "";

if statment {

    lootKey = "<button onclick='function take_key'>take</button>Key<br>";

    function take_key() {
        key = "key<br>";
        lootKey = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is invalid and is unlikely to run as you expect. Check the console for errors

Comment: you need to share the complete code.... with a working demo is possible

Comment: could you correct my code? i have no idea how to fix it

Comment: there is nothing to be corrected unless we know what is the problem... for that you need to share more info

Answer (score 0):

I can see couple of code that you should modify to get it working:

```
var lootKey = "";
var key = "";

if (statment) { //wrap your statement in parentheses

    lootKey = "<button onclick='take_key()'>take</button>Key<br>";//use take_key() to call a function

    function take_key() {
        key = "key<br>";
        lootKey = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

if (beginDone == true) {
            if (input == "GO") {

```
            var key = "";
            var lootKey = "";

            page = page + 1;
            healthPoints = healthPoints - 25;
            coins = coins + 25;
            lootKey = "<button onclick='function take_key()'>take</button>Key<br>";

            function take_key() {
                key = "key<br>";
                lootKey = "";
            }

            document.getElementById("hp").innerHTML = "Health Points: " + ("<a>" + healthPoints + "</a>");
            document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = "coins: " + ("<a>" + coins + "</a>");
            document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = "Page: " + ("<a>" + page + "</a>");
            document.getElementById("chapter").innerHTML = "Chapter: " + ("<a>" + chapter + "</a>");
            document.getElementById("text_inventory").innerHTML = "Inventory: <br><br>" + "<a>" + key + sword + shield + "</a>";
            document.getElementById("text_loot").innerHTML = "Loot: <br><br>" + "<a>" + lootKey + "</a>";

            $("<p class='c_light_grey'>You lost 25 hp, gained a key and gained 25 coins. There is a key lying on the ground in front of you.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(2000);
        }
    }
```